# How to get started with SQL Server Compact 4.0?

Tags: sql-server-ce

I've downloaded the install files and ran them, I get some binaries in my program files folder and I've added a reference in my project to the dll. But how the heck to I create the .sdf file? It feels like I'm missing some sort of obvious clue...

Edit: This is an old question and the documentation and tooling is not available.

Comment: Noocyte, this question does not show enough research, as this functionality is included in the base documentation for VS, and there are other similar questions already on StackOverflow, and many blog sites. A basic search on Google or StackOverflow would have provided many helpful results. If you've already tried some of those, it would be helpful for us if you linked which ones you've tried, and why they didn't work for you so we could more accurately help you.

Comment: Actually, at the time (more than a year ago) there was no such thing that I could find... In fact I found a blog post some time later that said that the tooling was not in place yet (don't remember details anymore). While I agree with your comment _now_ it just wasn't that easy way back when. Hope you can see my point here and take back to down-vote.

Comment: No problem, for some reason at quick glance I had flipped the date in my head, thought you had asked on Sep 10, 2011, not Sep 11, 2010!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceengine(v=VS.100).aspx) using the `SqlCeEngine` class to create a database and [SqlCeConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection.aspx) to start querying this database.

Answer (score 2):

You can use WebMatrix or http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com (standalone) to create SQL Server Compact 4.0 database files.

Answer (score 2):

VS 2010 SP1 contains support for SQL CE 4.0, but the SQL CE Toolbox is still a good tool.